# What powershell verb suits reloading a users profile?

Tags: powershell

I have a commandlet in my profile that reloads my user profile. Whenever I edit my profile VSCode warns me that the name I use—`Reload-Profile`—uses an unapproved verb.

While `Reload` seems like a sane, obvious and easily searchable verb to describe reloading a resource, I'd like to know what I should be using to keep PS happy. None of the candidates on the [list of approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon.Reset?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) seem to describe anything like reloading.

Here's the code BTW (I got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567650/how-to-reload-user-profile-from-script-file-in-powershell?rq=1))

```sh
  function Reload-Profile {
    @($Profile.AllUsersAllHosts,
    $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost,
    $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts,
    $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
    ) | ForEach-Object {
      if(Test-Path $_){
        Write-Host "Running $_" -foregroundcolor Magenta
        . $_
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possibly `sync` as listed in the approved verbs table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands

Comment: Sync seems a bit wrong though. I know I would never think of it when I was trying to work out what the command to reload the profile was.

Comment: It isn't so much a refresh as a `get-`. Example. You Get AD data, then Set it, then get it again.

Comment: Maybe Reset / Restore / Redo?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am restoring it, even though most times I run the commandlet it's because I have changed my profile.ps1, so it's not going back to a previous state, it's more of an update.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with Invoke. Running a command is Invoke-Command, running a expression is Invoke-Expression, running pester is Invoke-Pester, and when Pester wants to run a mock, it's with Invoke-Mock, etc.

Invoke is the goto verb for asking something to execute.